# SDK2 p3: Current Solution For Messaging Across Apps

Tags: rally

What is the current solution for messaging across Rally Apps in 2.0p3?

Neither Rally.Messages or window.parent.Rally.Messages seem to be available anymore, as per [this (probably now deprecated) example](https://gist.github.com/2845161)

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the API has changed in 2.0p3 for getting the MessageBus instance. You can now call Rally.environment.getMessageBus() to get it. Along with this change came the capability for different apps to send and receive messages to/from each other.

- Matt

Comment: Great, this works for the most part.  However, it throws an exception when I go to the app directly from the Rally menus (actually this was true via the p2 method as well).  When I hit "refresh" and start on the page, I get no exception, just when I navigate to the page with the Rally menus.  The exception is as follows: error sending message:  
TypeError
arguments: Array[2]
get message: function () { [native code] }
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set message: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
type: "non_object_property_call"
__proto__: Error